# Object of type class i want to test isn't getting recognized in the test class even though I referenced the class in the test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-framework-version

I have a public class called Calc, that I want to test using unit tests. So I created a unit test project and referenced the project to the Calc class in it, but when I want to create an object of type Calc in the test method to test it, I get an error saying the type or namespace could not be found. What should I do to get the test method to recognize the object?

This is the class, whose methods I want to test:

```
public class Calc
{
    public int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

And this is my test class:

```
namespace TestingCalc1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CalcTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldAdd5And4()
        {
            Calc a = new Calc();
            Assert.AreEqual(9,a.add(5,4));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that Calc isn't recognized in the test method.

> The type or namespace Calc could not be found

Comment: And I guess the error message continues _"...Are you missing a using directive?"_ Are you? like `using TheNameSpaceOfCalc;` at the top of your test code file?

Comment: I added "using" then the namespace of the class under test and it worked! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do 3 different things to get my Tests project to recognize items in another project. Credit goes to my colleague Alana Franklin for this answer. (She didn't want to post it herself):

1) I marked as public the classes, methods, and fields I needed for my test. Initially, most couldn't be found:

[image: Method and class not found by Intellisense]

2) I added a using for the project I wanted to test to the top of the test file. Initially, it couldn't be found, either.

[image: Intellisense can't find MyApp. Says "Using directive is unnecessary."]

3) I added the project I wanted to test as a dependency of the Tests project. Tests > Dependencies > right-click > check the project you want to test

[image: Tests > Dependencies > right-click > check the box for MyApp]

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer right click on **Tests Project** > **Properties**. Than check if target framework is the same as in your tested project.

[image]

Comment: Why downvote? This is exactly kind of error you can get when Target Framework is wrong